# Would watch() in Vue3 stop automatically at component unmounted?

Tags: javascript, watch, reactive, vuejs3

According to [Vue3 Doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#stopping-the-watcher), `watchEffect` will stop when a component is unmounted.

> When watchEffect is called during a component's setup() function or lifecycle hooks, the watcher is linked to the component's lifecycle and will be automatically stopped when the component is unmounted.

Does `watch` has the same behavior in term of automatically stoppage? Thanks!

Comment: It seems so. See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#shared-behavior-with-watcheffect.

Comment: @User28 It did mention `watch shares behavior with watchEffect in terms of manual stoppage`. Seems for manual stoppage but not automatically stoppage

Comment: Umm, I was confused too. The `manual stoppage` links to the `Stopping the Watcher` which talk about automatically stopped. I create [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wmbvzsn7/) to test. It seems that the watcher automatically stopped when the component is unmounted.

Comment: @User28 This is the answer. Thanks for you fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Watchers declared synchronously inside setup() or  are
> bound to the owner component instance, and will be automatically
> stopped when the owner component is unmounted. In most cases, you
> don't need to worry about stopping the watcher yourself.

Src: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#stopping-a-watcher

So the answer seems like, **yes** if you declare the watcher synchronously, and **no** if you declare it asynchronously.

It looks like `watch()/watchEffect()` return `unwatch()` functions that you have to call to stop asynchronously created watchers.

PS
This was mainly just a follow-up on @User28. The link in your comment was outdated but I couldn't edit it.